# <!DOCTYPE html> affecting height of a table

Tags: html, doctype, quirks-mode

When adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of the following HTML, the height of the table changes, as `p`'s margin is included inside the `td` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: solid 1px black;">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

E.g. in Chrome:

- with `<!DOCTYPE html>`: [image: rendering with doctype html]
- without `<!DOCTYPE html>`: [image: rendering without doctype html].

I know that omitting `DOCTYPE` will put the browser rendering in quirks mode and that the document won't be valid HTML, but still I am looking for a styling hack to make them render identically (at least in Chrome) - ideally with changing the table-related styles and not the `p` ones.

In my defense: I will render one and the same HTML in different contexts, with and without `<!DOCTYPE html>`, latter is third-party component which I don't have control on.

Comment: Try this `* {  box-sizing: border-box; }` - [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: *It’s not valid HTML5 if the doctype is missing*, so the browser can use whatever quirky rendering mode it chooses. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype: “DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. *When omitted, browsers tend to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some specifications*.”

Comment: @user2864740 You are right. But it happened that I am rendering this HTML in a third-party component, which creates `iframe` without adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` inside.

Comment: @AhmedTagAmer just tried this and it seems it's not working.

Comment: Have you contacted the 3rd party who created the component? No need for a headache if they listen to bug requests. They are allowed to produce valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

First, the specific quirk. This is (almost)¹ described in [15.3.9 Margin collapsing quirks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#margin-collapsing-quirks) of the HTML5 spec. The relevant parts of which are

> In quirks mode, any element with default margins that is the child of
> a body, td, or th element and has no substantial previous siblings is
> expected to have a user-agent level style sheet rule that sets its
> 'margin-block-start' property to zero.
>
> In quirks mode, any p element that is the child of a td or th element
> and has no substantial following siblings, is expected to have a
> user-agent level style sheet rule that sets its 'margin-block-end'
> property to zero.

The normal margin behaviour is described in [15.3.3 Flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#flow-content-3) which gives this rule:

```css
blockquote, figure, listing, p, plaintext, pre, xmp {
  margin-block-start: 1em; margin-block-end: 1em;
}
```

Since the quirks mode effect is a user-agent rule, we can simply include this normal margin behaviour in our CSS explicitly.

So for your case, to make the quirks mode behave like standards mode all you can add:

```css
p {
  margin-block-start: 1em; 
  margin-block-end: 1em;
}
```

or (again, for your case) to make standards mode behave like quirks mode you can add

```css
td p {
  margin-block-start: 0; 
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

---

<sub>¹ I say "almost", because it seems that neither Chrome nor Firefox follow these rules exactly. By the rules, if the p element was wrapped in a div (for example) element within the td element, then the p element's margins should be applied in quirks mode as they are in standards mode. And that's what Firefox does. But not Chrome.

On the other hand, Firefox doesn't appear to treat before and after pseudo-elements of the td element as substantial content which it should, and Chrome does.

 The fixes suggested above aren't affected by these differences, but the interop issues make finding any fix by applying CSS to the td element probably impossible.</sub>